# Iptables allow access via ssh tunnel to internal network

Tags: ssh, iptables

I am trying to restrict access on a server only to ssh by doing this. This is working nicely

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport $SSH_port -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport $SSH_port -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

However I would be using ssh port forwarding to access internal services in 127.0.0.1:port and in another internal_ip:port on a different virtual interface how can I achieve this?

The command that I'm using for ssh port forwarding:

```
ssh -2NqCgD 55555 -p $SSH_port user@server
```

I tried many combinations but with no success.

Excerpt from `/var/log/auth.log`

```
sshd[xxxx]: error: connect_to 127.0.0.1 port xxxxx: failed.
sshd[xxxx]: error: connect_to internal_ip port yyyyy: failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule worked for me.
Order is important to iptables so placing the DROPs at the end did the trick.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport $ssh_port -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport $ssh_port -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 

iptables -A INPUT -i $internal_interface -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $internal_interface -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Allow all on loopback
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo  -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT 
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -o lo  -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I would remove the source and destination specifications. Reason being is if a host talks to itself with its public IP, it will still go over the loopback interface. Though if we dont care about that, then your answer is fine.

Comment: Thanks Adrien and Patrick this worked for me partly. I figured out how it should work. See my answer